# Do anyone know about the Skand Upa-Puran?

Tags: skanda-purana

Can anyone provide any information regarding the Skand Up Puran? **I am not talking about the Skand Mahapuran**, it is written in Koorma Purana that out of the 18 Upa Puranas, there is a Up Puran named **Skand Upa-Puran** apart from the Skand Mahapuran.
[image]
So, anyone having any knowledge about the same, do reply, and please attach a pdf copy of the Upa-Puran, if available online.

Answer (score 1):

Skanda upapurāṇa find it's mention in Purāṇic verses like above, and in traditional listing of it as upapurāṇa like in [*Purāṇasāra of Śrī Vidyāraṇya*](https://archive.org/details/puranasara-of-vidyaranya-critical-edition-hs-phatak-2000-mori/page/5/mode/1up). Though other listings like that in [*Prasthānabheda by Śrī Madhusūdana Sarasvatī*](https://archive.org/details/Prasthanabheda.by.Madhusudana.Sarasvati/page/n11/mode/1up) replaces it with "Nandī".

Noting the above difference, Śrīman R. C. Hazra in his *[Studies in the Upapurāṇas (vol.2)](https://archive.org/details/in.gov.ignca.18862/page/n19/mode/2up)* , while classifying it as a ***lost Śākta upapurāṇa*** mentions that the Skanda upapurāṇa is nothing but an alias for Nandī upapurāṇa, as being originally declared by Śrī Kārttikeya, Nandī upapurāṇa was also called 'Skanda'. Drawing the parallels, he presents his justification of so conclusion, based on some pramāṇa-s. You can read those [here](https://archive.org/details/in.gov.ignca.18862/page/477/mode/2up).

He proceeds to contemplate on the nature of the upapurāṇa, based on the verses quoted in other extant works. While, he acknowledges the vaiṣṇava nature of some quoted verse and the fact that Revā-khaṇḍa of Skanda Purāṇa connect the Skanda upapurāṇa with the Viṣṇu purāṇa as part of the latter (mentioning it as Śaukeya); he is of the opinion as based on predominant Śaiva-Śākta quotations that the upapurāṇa is either Śaiva or Śākta, while (as said above) classifying it as Śākta.

About the topics dealt within, the author states it to be revolving around prominently with donation and it's types. The extant quotes also concern themselves with digging tanks, feeding cow, visiting holy places, and avoiding meat among many others. Even in Caturvarga cintāmaṇi, with quoting the upapurāṇa with the name of Nandī, discusses various topics connected with Śrāddha. You can read these profoundly in the aforementioned link.

P.S: It seems, there is a part of Skanda upapurāṇa still extant with the name of "Śiva bhakti vilāsa". As per MS. it seems to be 79th chapter of the original upapurāṇa. You can read it with the vyākhyā of someone named Narasiṃh [here](https://archive.org/details/shiva-bhakti-vilas-part-1-in-skand-upapuran-by-nrisingha-printed-jangamwadi-math-collection/page/n1/mode/2up).